# Chunked encoding issue in web.py

Tags: python, web.py, chunked-encoding

I have my web.py application running. It receives POST request from outside. The request header contains `transfer-encoding: chunked`. When i try to read the data with `web.data()` the process starts consuming enormous amount of memory and after couple of minutes server dies.

I have a doubt of this `transfer-encoding` type. Does anyone faced same kinda issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is because just a few web server considered request have a body with chunk.
SimpleHTTPServer inside python will crush in this situation. tornado is OK, but can't get body with wsgi.input. gevent is fine, but webpy don't process right. You can fix this problem with those code.

```
def data():
    if 'data' not in ctx:
        if ctx.env.get('HTTP_TRANSFER_ENCODING') == 'chunked':
            ctx.data = ctx.env['wsgi.input'].read()
        else:
            cl = intget(ctx.env.get('CONTENT_LENGTH'), 0)
            ctx.data = ctx.env['wsgi.input'].read(cl)
    return ctx.data
```

Of cause, you should use those code with gevent.